# List Pull request using the Github API in the pre-request-script from Postman

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script, octokit-js

I have to retrieve the Github pull request, using the url:

`https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/pulls/<pr_number>` and the repo

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>
```

I tried to use `Octokit.js` -> `https://github.com/octokit/core.js#readme` as is suggested in the Github documentation. I am using the next code:

```
pm.sendRequest("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rest.js/15.2.6/octokit-rest.js", (err, res) => {

    pm.collectionVariables.set("octokit", res.text());
    eval(pm.collectionVariables.get("octokit"));
    // eval will evaluate the JavaScript code and intialize the min.js
})
```

But it seems like it is not the correct way to use the `octokit` library in Postman. I got the next error:

```
There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:Error: window is not defined
```

I followed the next approach to import external libraries in Postman, using a Pull a library from CDN approach

```
https://blog.postman.com/adding-external-libraries-in-postman/
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using math.js in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64651464/using-math-js-in-postman)

Comment: My error is that I am getting a window is not defined error message, maybe is the CDN version I am using I guess, I used the same approach that you pasted

Comment: The error happens in the eval method

Comment: Please have a look at the answer I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64669720/641135